# How can you add a String to a list of Monads in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads, composition, functor

I am a new to functional programming. I am scraping a website using [Scalpel](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/scalpel) and I need to extract information from links contained in that website. What I can extrapolate though is just part of the link and I need to add to the String `"http://www.google.com/"` to each of these links. I can't do a normal `++` because I don't have a list of `String`s.

Here's the code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Text.HTML.Scalpel

main :: IO ()
main = do
  res <- scrapeURL "http://www.whateverLink/" scrapeComic
  print res

scrapeComic :: Scraper String [[String]]
scrapeComic =
  chroots ("ul" @: ["id" @= "research-teachinglist"]) scrapeLink

scrapeLink :: Scraper String [String]
-- This returns me the parts of the links I want 
scrapeLink = (attrs "href" "a")

-- I tried this, but it doesn't work
-- scrapeLink = mapM_ ("http://www.google.com/" ++) (attrs "href" "a")
```

Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: `fmap (map ("http://www.google.com/" ++))  scrapeLink`, but you should probably have a look at the typeclassopedia. This question is more or less asking for a monad tutorial, which is off-topic on SO.

Comment: That worked! I will look at some monad tutorials. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

```
attrs "href" "a" :: Scraper String [String]
```

and

```
("http://www.google.com/" ++) :: String -> String
```

and you'd like to apply the latter to all the `String` elements in the former's result list.

First of all, applying it to lists is a matter of

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

so in your case, you have

```
map ("http://www.google.com/" ++) :: [String] -> [String]
```

Which gets us one step closer.

Now the next problem is that instead of a pure `[String]` value, you have a computation `Scraper String [String]`. However, [`Scraper str` is an instance of `Functor`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/scalpel-0.4.0/docs/Text-HTML-Scalpel.html#t:Scraper) for any choice of `str`, in particular, for `str ~ String`, i.e. `Scraper String` is a `Functor`.

What that gives us is a way of applying pure functions to `Scraper String`s:

```
fmap :: (a -> b) -> Scraper String a -> Scraper b
```

in particular, we have

```
fmap (map ("http://www.google.com/" ++)) :: Scraper String [String]
```

leading to

```
scrapeLink :: Scraper String [String]
scrapeLink = fmap (map ("http://www.google.com/" ++)) (attrs "href" "a")
```